# Customizing Select in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-widget

I have the following model

```
class Color(models.Model):
    """
    Colors
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="name", unique=True)
    hex = models.CharField(max_length=6, db_column="hex", unique=True)
```

This model is foreignkey for some other model, so represented as dropdown list.
I want to modify this list so it looks like

```
<select>
<option style="background-color:#hex1">name1</option>
<option style="background-color:#hex2">name2</option>
</select>
```

I know that django already does this, except the styling.
I also know that I need to extend select Widget and override `render_option` method, but I don't know how to pass hex values to new widget.
How can I d this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your purpose in doing this? If you want to style the form, you should use css. Background-color variable you are supplying is also invalid.

Comment: I want visual color choice instead of simple. How CSS will help if each option has different background?

Comment: Are you trying to create a select with an image or swatch displayed next to the option text?

Comment: I don't want to select with image. I just want to set background of option based on value from db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question you can just use basic django templates. Let's say you're passing the QuerySet of colours as `colours`, then you'd use:

```
<select>
{% for colour in colours %}
<option style="background-color:#{{ colour.hex }}">{{ colour.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```